# Can substitute default softmax with self-implemented one in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just wonder could the softmax provided by the TensorFlow package, namely, tensorflow.nn.softmax, be substituted by one implemented by myself?

I run the original tutorial file mnist_softmax.py with cross_entropy calculation:

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(tf.nn.softmax(y)), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

it will give a cross validate accuracy rate 0.9195, it quite makes sense.

However, I do some changes, like below:

```
# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

# The below two lines are added by me, an equivalent way to calculate softmax, at least in my opinion
y1 = tf.reduce_sum(y)
y2 = tf.scalar_mul(1.0 / y1, y)

# Define loss and optimizer
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

...
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y2), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

However, the cross validate accuracy rate is only 0.098.

Anyone has any insight into this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your `y2` as a matter of fact is not equivalent to computing softmax. Softmax is

```
softmax(y) = e^y / S
```

Where `S` is a normalizing factor (the sum of `e^y` across all `y`s). Also, when you compute the normalizing factor, you only need to reduce the sum over the classes, not over the samples. More proper way would be

```
y1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(y), reduction_indices=[1])
y2 = tf.scalar_mul(1.0 / y1, tf.exp(y))
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction and I am sorry for my carelessness. Yes, things turn much better after adopting your code. However I just drop reduction_indices=[1] since the python interpreter complains.